# Similar do AdMob para Desktop?

Tags: windows, aplicação-desktop, admob, ad

Existe? Quero fazer um programa free mas gostaria de ter anúncio em locais específicos dele.

E cobrar a licença para poder retirar isso, como funciona nos apps hoje.

Infelizmente o Google (até onde encontrei) não permite utilizar o sistema dele em programas desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[AdsJumbo](https://adsjumbo.com/) é uma rede de anunciantes semelhante ao Adsense e Admob, só que no caso, focado para aplicações e jogos para Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Tecnicamente é possível carregando o código web em um pequeno visualizador (objeto) da web no programa. Na documentação não encontrei nada que proíba essa utilização, porém nota-se que eles incentivam o uso apenas para mobile.

O Google Adsense proíbe especificamente exibir seus anúncios em outras coisas que não sejam sites apropriados (porque eles querem poder olhar a página com seus bots). Mas outras redes de anúncios podem estar ok.